# How do I install lua dev libraries on MacOS?

Tags: macos, lua, homebrew, luarocks, domoticz

I need to install liblua5.3-dev for compiling a code project called Domoticz. I tried using 'brew' and 'luarocks' but it seems it doesn't provide me the development libraries but only a runtime/interpretor.
How do I install liblua5.3-dev on macOS (Catalina)?

Answer (score 3):

You should just try the [official way](https://www.lua.org/download.html):

```
curl -R -O http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.5.tar.gz
tar zxf lua-5.3.5.tar.gz
cd lua-5.3.5
make macosx test
```

Comment: I tried as well and in the end they all work. It was a problem with the makefile